# Change Rviz's View Types in launch file?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i used Rviz in launch file like :

```
<node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" args="-d $(find hector_slam_launch)/rviz_cfg/mapping_demo.vcg"/>
```

but i wanna change "TopDownOrtho" view to "XYorbit" view in launch file. how can I?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63811/change-rviz%27s-view-types-in-launch-file?/) by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2013-05-28

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can edit the config file that ur loading at the time of launch. There will be a parameter "camera\type" in config file.

Hope it helps..

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) on 2013-05-28**:
Thank you :) do you know "camera\type" params in ".vcg" file?

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-05-29**:
I am not sure about that but you can check in rviz source file..or just change it in rviz and then save it. This will automatically update it in in config file which u can refer later..

**Comment by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) on 2013-06-07**:
Thank you :)

**Comment by [galou](https://answers.ros.org/users/14171/galou/) on 2014-04-09**:
I think this does not answer the question. I would also like to change some parameters in the launch file. For example, I would like to change the topic name of a visualization element in RViz without having to copy the rviz file.